# bash script while loop if variable is true

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash script:

```
while [ $loop == "true" ]
   do
     //do stuff
   done
```

but it says error at [.

Also this runs as a daemon, when the stop argument is passed to the script...the loop should. I'm guessing setting $loop to false will automatically end the loop.

Comment: "... it says error at [." Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to type this would be:

```
while [ "$loop" = "true" ]
```

Read the section "Working out the test-command" at the following URL:
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: All values in bash are strings. The quotes have nothing to do with that.

Comment: The quotes makes it work. And = compares strings, compared to (for example) -eq that compares integers. Check Advanced Bash Scripting Guide for more information "Note that integer and string comparison use a different set of operators.": http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Or well, you are right, the "" in itself doesn't make it a string, you might aswell use: $loop = true but bash still makes difference between strings and integers. Updated the answer slightly.

Comment: The reasoning is still incorrect. `$ [ true = "true" ] ; echo $?`
`0`

Comment: You know, telling someone they are wrong without explaining and properly correcting is kindof pointless and dumb?

Comment: I make a habit of quoting the string matching in a test case with "" in both the left and right values, it makes it less likely that I would forget "" when you have a string containing spaces, etc.

Comment: Or as GreyCat would have said: [Use More Quotes!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Idiot)

Answer (score 6):

M. Vazquez-Abrams is quite right.  This is nothing to do with quotation marks making things that are *already* strings into strings, or some wrongheaded idea that `=` in `bash`'s built-in `[` command is anything other than a string comparison.  (Read § 6.4 of the Bash User Manual, people!)  It's everything to do with what happens to empty fields after field-splitting turns words into fields.

If the shell variable `loop` is empty or null, then `$loop` expands to an empty field.  After field splitting, empty fields are discarded.  Note that field splitting and the check for empty fields *precedes* quote removal.  So `"$loop"` expands to the field `""`, which is *not* empty and is thus not removed.  After quote removal it is then an empty field, that becomes an empty argument to the command.

The `[` command requires its `=` operator to have two operands, fore and aft.  Anything else is a syntax error.  Since an empty field is removed, the sequence of words

```
[ $loop = true ]
```

expands to *four* fields

1. `[`
2. `=`
3. `true`
4. `]`

when the `[` command needs *five* to be syntactically correct:

1. `[`
2. 
3. `=`
4. `true`
5. `]`

Of course, the empty string is not equal to the four-character string `true`, and the command's exit status is non-zero.

Again, all of this is in the Bash User Manual, in §3.5 and §3.5.7.  The manual is your friend.

Comment: Oh yes, you are ofcourse right. Well put! I much more appreciate these types of corrections and explanations though than Mr Vazquez-Abrams arrogant comments just pointing out that someone is wrong without bothering to explain or clarify. Hardly helpful. I phrased myself badly with converting to string, but I meant there is a difference between strings and integers in how you're supposed to loop them. And I always have a habit of putting my tests/strings within "" to handle spaces properly. :) I also wrongly assumed that $loop was set to "true", while it might not have been.